Manage Access to file shares Azure
I created a file share system with 9 file shares that go to different people.
I can't limit access or specify who should have access to what.
I've read a bunch of documentation, but I don't think I understand it correctly.
I tried to give access through Access Control(IAM) I can see that the correct people are in the correct file share, but in practice every person has access to all the file shares.
I read about ACLs but that is for containers, and I want to used file shares for structured data. And a documentation about entra authentication.
I have tried enabling, Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS), Microsoft Entra Domain Services & Microsoft Entra Kerberos. And looked in the configurations. Set share-level permissions.
If something is unclear, please ask.

You need control limited access for particular user like user A needs to access share 1 and user B needs to access share 2. but User A don't need to access the share 2 is it correct?

Exactly @Venkatesan

have you found anyway to achieve this ?


You need to control limited access for particular users, such as User A needing access to Share 1 and User B needing access to Share 2. However, User A does not need to access Share 2. Is this correct? - Exactly

According to this MS-Document,
As far as I know, the above scenario can be achieved by ABAC role assignments, but it supports only Azure blob storage and data lake storage.
By referring to this MS-Document, this role assignment can be done by assigning the Storage Blob Contributor role to a user with a condition like below:
Portal:

However, in Azure File Share, we cannot assign the role with a condition as of now.
To assign share level permissions, the only way is to follow this Document.
The above document will give you an idea of authentication as identity-based access in the Azure file share, which you can enable with Active Directory Domain Service, Microsoft Entra Domain Services, or Microsoft Entra Kerberos.
Afterward, you can assign Share level permissions via the portal, CLI, or PowerShell.
Reference:
Use Microsoft Entra Domain Services with Azure Files | Microsoft Learn
